# C#: operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' error

Tags: c#

So I have almost completed my program but I keep getting this error for the subtraction operator. I have searched throughout my book and the internet but can find no fix for this. Is anybody able to tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int int1;
        int int2;
        char oper;

        Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
        int1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter operator (+,-,*, / or %)");
        oper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter first integer: ");
        int2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if(oper == '+')
            Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 + int2);

        if (oper == '-')
            Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 - int2);

        if(oper == '*')
            Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 * int2);

        if(oper == '/')
            Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 / int2);

        if(oper == '%')
            Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 % int2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try wrapping inside `()`: `Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 - int2));`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Why does the '-' operator require () unlike the others?

Comment: A word of advice, Use Switch/if..else..if in stead of so many if.

Comment: That would definitely clean it up a bit, thanks

Comment: It is not the operator. It is the context. Actually, you should enclose all your results in parenthesis if you wish to have the desired result. For example "Answer is: "+int1+int2 will return "Answer is: 32", if int1 is 3 and int2 is 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Answer is: " + int1 - int2);
```

You are first concatenating a string with int1, resulting in a string. 
Then you try to substract this string with int2.

Try this :

```
Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 - int2));
```

Thus you will first evaluate `(int1 - int2)` and then concatenate it.

By the way, you will also have to do it for the '+' operator. Else you will concatenate int2 to int1.
For the other operators, it should work thanks to the precedence on '+'.

Comment: `... for very operator` - [not so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). `*`, `/` and `%` have higher precedence than `+`. Whether he *should* do it for every operator is another matter :)

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure precedence would work the same with different types

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.Write("Answer is: {0} ",int1 - int2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma to separate parameters in Console.Write and use a placeholder {0}, like so:

```
Console.Write("Answer is: {0}", int1 - int2);
```

This does not confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(oper == '+')
        Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 + int2));

    if (oper == '-')
        Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 - int2));

    if(oper == '*')
        Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 * int2);

    if(oper == '/')
        Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 / int2));

    if(oper == '%')
        Console.Write("Answer is: " + (int1 % int2));
```